# Simplejson strange behavior

Tags: python, json, simplejson

So In python I make a dictionary in JSON structure

```
>>> a = {"name":'nikhil',"age":25}
```

Now I check if `a` is a Valid JSON using http://jsonlint.com/
. I get it's valid.

Now I do :

```
>>> b = simplejson.dumps(a)
>>> b= '{"age": 25, "name": "nikhil"}'
```

Now I do:

```
>>> c = simplejson.loads(b)
>>> c = {'age': 25, 'name': 'nikhil'}
```

Now I check if `c` is a Valid JSON I get error.

Why is Simplejson is not able to convert JSON string back to valid JSON? when I started with a valid JSON only?

Comment: I don't understand. `c` is not JSON at all, it's a Python dictionary. Plus you are doing `c = {'age': 25, 'name': 'nikhil'}` at the end which basically makes all of your convertions pointless.

Comment: Yeah but the why are the double quotes removed in `c` and single quotes added. When I started with double quotes in `a`. In JSON key should always be in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing JSON with Python here. `b` is a JSON-formatted string, `c` is a *Python object*.

Python syntax just happens to look a lot like JSON (JavaScript) in that respect.

- Python strings can use either `'` or `"`, depending on the contents; JSON always uses `"`. You entered `a` using double quotes for the keys, single quotes for the one string value; if you asked Python to echo it back for you you'll find it'll be shown with only single quotes.
- Python booleans are `True` or `False`, JSON uses `true` and `false`.
- The JSON 'empty' value is `null`, Python uses `None` instead.

See the [Encoders and Decoders section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) of the `json` module for an overview how JSON and Python objects are mapped.